# Android: RoundRectShape: Modify corner radii

Tags: android, ondraw, shapedrawable

I have a `RoundRectShape` that is drawn in a `View`'s `onDraw()` function.

The corners of this shape are modified by any drag actions on this view through an overridden `onTouchEvent` function (which calls `invalidate()` to force the call to `onDraw()`).

When initialising variables in `onDraw`, Eclipse shows a warning saying **Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)**.

This issue is explained as follows:

**You should avoid allocating objects during a drawing or layout operation. These are called frequently, so a smooth UI can be interrupted by garbage collection pauses caused by the object allocations.**

**The way this is generally handled is to allocate objects up front and to reuse them for each drawing operation**

To do this I obviously have to be able to modify the corner radii as set in the constructor. The [RoundedRectShape class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html) provides no setter (and I am pretty sure the related member variables are inaccessible).

I know it is a small object and a minor issue, but how can I change these corners without reinitializing the Object when the only method the class provides for setting the radii of the rounded corners is through the constructor?

Or is this just a case where doing the best thing will have to be replaced with doing what is possible?

Thanks,

P.S. Calling the constructor in the `onTouchEvent()` method will remove the warning but accomplishes absolutely nothing due to the fact that `onDraw()` is called every time through `invalidate()` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `RoundRectShape` at all. `RoundRectShape` is immutable so the only way to change its values is to use reflection.
You can easily accomplish the same drawnings by calling `Canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF rect, float rx, float ry, Paint paint)` method directly without using `RoundRectShape`. Or you can look at `RoundRectShape` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.java) and just use its code in your `onDraw()` method.

**EDIT:**
The comments about `RoundRectShape` not being the right way to go and looking at the implementation were right. Following the implementation found a call to:

```
mPath.addRoundedRect()
```

which has a variation allowing a float of corner radii as the input ([Path.addRoundRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addRoundRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Path.Direction%29))

In answering the question:

**Use a path instead of a shape as the variable and draw the new Rounded Rectangle to the path when necessary**

Comment: I have looked at that draw command. The issue I have there is that not all of the corners for my shape have the same radii. And I could only find that call which sets them all the same.That implementation link is a great suggestion but, thanks. I didn't expect to really get anywhere with this, but I like that idea.