# Drawable.Dynamic change ShapeSize

Tags: android, drawable

I have some problem. When button will be pressed - size of shape must be changed.
One variant is to create new object with new size, but i think it is stupid.  Help me please,or write your ideas how to make it!

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
ShapeDrawable d1;
ShapeDrawable d2;
    //
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
    d1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    d2 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    ImageView ob1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView ob2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    d1.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
    d1.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
    d1.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    ob1.setImageDrawable(d1);

    d2.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
    d2.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
    d2.getPaint().setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    ob2.setImageDrawable(d2);

    Button btn_ob1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_ob1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            d1.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
            d1.invalidateSelf();
                            d1.setIntrinsicHeight(150);
                            d1.setIntrinsicWidth(150);
        }
    });
    Button btn_ob2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn_ob2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d2.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
            d2.invalidateSelf();
                            d2.setIntrinsicHeight(150);
                            d2.setIntrinsicWidth(150);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is because of ShapeDrawable is an immutable object, like RoundRectShape in the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11491670/925070