# Create and iterate a list of Strings in Java

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I'm trying to create list of arrays, dynamic in size, add elements and iterate through them when I finish.  Currently my code is:

```
    String activities = "SELECT DISTINCT phoneactivity from ContextTable030313";
    ArrayList<String> myActivities = new ArrayList();

    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(activities, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            myActivities.add(cursor.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("ts")));

        } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
    }
```

Yet it fails to run in the do loop.  I believe I am declaring something incorrectly and I get the following warnings:

```
- ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized
    - Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)
    - Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to 
     ArrayList<String>
```

yet I do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: pre Java 7, <String> should come in both sides. ie new ArrayList<String>() as well

Comment: I did that and I still get the following warning: "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)" AND my code still fails in the do loop....

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490611/android-roundrectshape-modify-corner-radii

Comment: It sounds like that warning is telling you that you're accessing the database from the wrong place/thread.  Maybe if you hit the database and initialize _myActivities_ in the correct place, your loop will work better.  That being said, I have no idea what framework/platform you're using... Swing?  Android?

Comment: Try to print `cursor.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("ts"))` in your console what exactly printing this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your arrayList declaration such that it accepts **parameterized type** during constructor invokation.

```
ArrayList<String> myActivities = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you use java 7 or above:

```
ArrayList<String> myActivities = new ArrayList<>();
```

You don't need to declare the parametreized type during constructor invokation due to **Type inference**but you still need to declare empty <>.

Comment: I did that and I still get the following warning:  "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse 
 instead)"  AND my code still fails in the do loop....

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this:

> Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to 
>        ArrayList

Which points out to this line of code:

```
ArrayList<String> myActivities = new ArrayList();
```

You should change that line to this:

```
ArrayList<String> myActivities = new ArrayList<String>();
```

On a different note, you could replace this code segment:

```
  if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            myActivities.add(cursor.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("ts")));

        } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
    }
```

With this:

```
  while (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {       
        myActivities.add(cursor.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("ts")));       
    }
```