# Android Canvas: Create RoundRectShape Object

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, shapedrawable, android-shapedrawable

I have created a class for a rectangle shape as it is an object in my application. However now I would like the corners to be rounded. Below you can see it's a bare bones class to create as many rectangles I want with the same attributes.

```
public class customDrawable extends ShapeDrawable {

    public void setCustomDrawableAttributes(ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable){
       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;
       int width = 100;
       int height = 100;
       shapeDrawable.setBounds(x, y-height, x + width,y+height );
   }

   public ShapeDrawable createShape(){
       return new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
   }

}
```

Update: Without this method I have nothing will be drawn as there is no size. With it it only draws the usual rectangle. (Integer values where changed to not show app specific methods)

```
public void setDrawableAttributes(ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable){
   int x = 0;
   int y = 500
   int width = 200
   int height = 300
   shapeDrawable.setBounds(x, y-height, x + width,y+height );
```

}

From my research I found that I cannot simply add rounded corners but instead have to create a `RoundRectShape shapeDrawable`. Every attempt I have made to create a rectangle with rounded corners using this `RoundRectShape` has failed. Somehow the shape always ends up being a regular rectangle with no rounded corners.

I am looking for a just bare bones class (like the one provided) that creates a roundRectShape drawable. Height and width does not matter as long as it has rounded corners. Must be in Java and not XML.

Links I have tried for creating round rectangles:

1.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html

2.http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.java.shtml

3.https://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52c5d269da0a37e1836d6e75/android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape?tag=coyote

4.http://developer.oesf.biz/em/developer/reference/durian/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html

5.https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.java

6.[Android: RoundRectShape: Modify corner radii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490611/android-roundrectshape-modify-corner-radii)

7.http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape

8.http://www.edumobile.org/android/shape-drawing-example-in-android/
9.http://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape/

Comment: using shape drawable from xml wont work in your case?

Comment: Maybe I suppose since they will be the same every time. Can you give an example?

Comment: I think programmatic is probably still better tho. I am assuming more options. Why xml instead?

Comment: You can customize xml shapes very efficiently. And yes, it will keep your code cleaner too.

Comment: I have tried that. Does not work for me.

Comment: After that I have a method to set the grounds attributes. I will update post. Either without this method nothing gets drawn or The method is used and there are no curves

Comment: If you could answer the post with a class that uses this (similar to the rectangle one added in the question) and generated a round rect that is tested that would be very appreciative and I would be happy to mark it as correct. Thanks,

Comment: Cannot set the viee like that. I have many drawables tgat are being drawn onto the canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a class `MyRect` that is used to draw rounded Rect for you.

```
public class MyRect {

    public static Paint paint;  // default paint use for all my MyRect objects

    static {

        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public float x,y,width,height;
    public float roundStrength=30;

    public MyRect(float x, float y, float width,float height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }

    public MyRect(float x, float y, float width,float height,float roundStrength){
        this(x,y,width,height);
        this.roundStrength=roundStrength;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
         canvas.drawRoundRect(x-width/2,y-height/2,x+width/2,y+height/2,roundStrength,roundStrength,paint);
    }
}
```

Creating objects of above `MyRect` is not enough, we need to keep references of objects in any container so that we can modify or delete that object in future.

```
static ArrayList<MyRect> myRects=new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of `View`/`SurfaceView` call MyRect's `draw()` method.

```
for(MyRect rect:myRects)
    rect.draw(canvas);
```

Done, Create object and add to container.

```
myRects.add(new MyRect(touchx,touchy,100,100));
```

or

```
myRects.add(new MyRect(touchx,touchy,100,100,50));
```

You can also extends `MyRect`like add some more constructor, method and data member according to your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

**Custom Drawable**

You can create custom drawable by extending drawable class

*Steps to create Custom Drawable*

1.Subclass Drawable and implement the following methods methods

- `public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas)` - You will get a canvas object to draw shapes.Call getBounds() method here to get the dimensions according view in which we applied the drawable.
- `public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha)` - You will get a alpha integer value here,set it your main paint in which you are drawing the shape.
- `public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter)` - You will get ColorFilter object  here,set it your main paint in which you are drawing the shape.
- `public int getOpacity()` - Return the opacity value here like PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT,PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT,PixelFormat.RGB_888 etc.

2.In `onDraw()` call canvas.drawRoundRect() method to draw the shape

- `public void drawRoundRect(@android.support.annotation.NonNull android.graphics.RectF rect,float rx,float ry,@android.support.annotation.NonNull android.graphics.Paint paint)`

  Draw the specified round-rect using the specified paint. The roundrect 
  will be filled or framed based on the Style in the paint.

  Parameters:

  1) rect - The rectangular bounds of the roundRect to be drawn
   2) rx - The x-radius of the oval used to round the corners
   3) ry - The y-radius of the oval used to round the corners
   4) paint - The paint used to draw the roundRect

*Code Sample*

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.IntRange;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * Created by jinesh on 24/5/17.
 */

public class RoundedRectangle extends Drawable {
    private Paint rectPaint;
    private RectF drawableBounds;
    public RoundedRectangle(int rectBackground) {
        rectPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        rectPaint.setColor(rectBackground);
        drawableBounds=new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        Rect bounds=getBounds();
        drawableBounds.set(bounds.left,bounds.top,bounds.right,bounds.bottom);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawableBounds,10,10,rectPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
       rectPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
       rectPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Set to any view from activity

```
 RoundedRectangle roundedRectangle=new RoundedRectangle(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
 textView.setBackground(roundedRectangle);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. I marked the other one as correct because it works better for my implementation however I will for sure use yours when I need to set backgrounds and that. Thanks! Hope you get a lot of votes.Great info, picture, very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `drawRoundRect` function of the `Canvas` class?

public class RoundRect{
        int l,r,t,b,rx,ry;
        Paint paint;

```
    public RoundRect(int l,int r,int t,int b,int rx,int ry,Paint paint){
        this.l=l;
        this.r=r;
        this.t=t;
        this.b=b;
        this.paint=paint;
    }
    public void draw(Canvas c,Paint paint){ 
        c.drawRoundRect(l,t,r,b,rx,ry,paint);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Because I have many objects. For better coding I should have my objects as classes. Not just canvas.drawSomething. The application will get bigger anyways which will make that kind of coding hard to manage.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean... It is possible to define a class for your rounded rectangle with it's parameters (position, size...) and use `drawRoundRect` when you need to draw it.

Comment: Can you provide a java class example? It is not good to draw directly onto the canvas via `canvas.drawRect` for example. It is better to create objects that you can control all parameters in methods and just create a new object every time.

Comment: You can try this : public class RoundRect{
  int l,r,t,b,rx,ry;
  Paint paint;
  
  public RoundRect(int l,int r,int t,int b,int rx,int ry,Paint paint){
   this.l=l;
   this.r=r;
   this.t=t;
   this.b=b;
   this.paint=paint;
  }
  
  public void draw(Canvas c,Paint paint){
   c.drawRoundRect(l,t,r,b,rx,ry,paint);
  }
 }

Comment: Can you add this as an answer? And i will try it

Comment: Tried cannot get it to work. I need a full example. an object extending roundRect or RoundRectShape to create a rectangle with rounded corners.